# Can anyone give me a list of people mentioned in our ancient texts who attained Siddhis through meditation only

Tags: vedas, puranas, hanuman, demi-god, supernatural

By siddhis, i mean the superpowers mentioned in Hanuman Chalisa, Asta Siddhis like growing large and small, flying and other powers.

Can someone give me a list of people who attained super powers through meditation only.